# Logback internal exception being silently ignored

Tags: java, logback

I'm learning JAVA, and today am playing with Logback.  As an exercise to myself, I wrote a custom "appender" to write logs (for Spring) to a MongoDB collection.  After tracking down a bug, I found that if my appender throws an exception, then this is just silently ignored, and the application continues running but with the logger in question now having died.

The place an exception is thrown:

```
public class MongoDBAppender extends AppenderBase<ILoggingEvent> {
   ...
  protected void append(ILoggingEvent event) {
    ...
    throw new RuntimeException("My example exception!");
```

As I want to open a single MongoDB session right at the start, and then start logging, and then get Spring going, I programmatically set this appender going:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost:27017");

LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
PatternLayoutEncoder ple = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
ple.setContext(lc);
ple.setPattern("%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n");
ple.start();

MongoDBAppender mongoDBAppender = new MongoDBAppender();
mongoDBAppender.setContext(lc);
mongoDBAppender.setEncoder(ple);
mongoDBAppender.setmongoDBName("test");
mongoDBAppender.setmongoDBCollectionName("my_log");
mongoDBAppender.start();

Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.springframework");
logger.addAppender(mongoDBAppender);
logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
logger.setAdditive(false);
```

Other loggers are defined as usual in `logback.xml`.

So, as is, this application runs correctly, but nothing is logged for `org.springframework`.  If I change the `logback.xml` file to start as:

```
<configuration debug="true">
```

then I get a full debug output from Logback itself, and indeed then I do see my exception being thrown.

> Is there any way to get this sort of output if and only if there is an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, it seems that the `doAppend` method in `AppenderBase` catches exceptions and logs them to the internal Logback log: this is only ever displayed if we have used the `<configuration debug="true">` option.  The `doAppend` method is what actually calls my custom `append`.

My work-around: catch all exceptions myself in `append` and then log them to my own logger (for MongoDBAppender).  Then we can decide how (or if) to display such messages.